# lvs File descriptor 6 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 8379: -bash

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

When ever running lvs , pvs or vgs its giving me below error

[root@onrequest # lvs
File descriptor 6 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 8379: -bash

I have tried below command which is successful and I got a solution

echo "export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1" >> /etc/environment
echo "export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1" >> /etc/profile

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below command which is successful and I got a solution

echo "export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1" >> /etc/environment echo "export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1" >> /etc/profile